# JavaScript not working when moved to an external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had working a java script in my html page.Now i moved the script to an external js file.
here is the script(jful.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#catnav').offset().top;

    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
        // otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
            $('#catnav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
        } else {
            $('#catnav').css({ 'position': 'relative' }); 
        }   
    };

    // run our function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

});
</script>
```

Now the script is not working.
I included the script like this

```
<head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jful.js"></script></head>
```

When i again add the script directly to HTML document ,it works !(this script is execute when we scroll down the page ) What is the problem ??

Comment: Please add the error message you get or get your question closed because people can only guess what's the problem and then they guess wrong and then you say not working and then they guess again and that's wrong again and so on. P.S. It's probably not working because the original wrong file is fetched from cache

Comment: Sorry,I won't repeat it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove these

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and

```
</script>
```

Comment: Did you checked your js path.

Comment: @AshwinSingh he had called that => `$(function() {`

Comment: It could be because of your path. Is it in the same directory as your page?

Comment: Thanks,the problem was of path.I am using WordPress so i need to add

Comment: <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/jful.js"></script>

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` in jful.js.

Answer (score 1):

if you have added `<script type="text/javascript">` into your JS file remove the  tags, you should just include plain JS code into the .js files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. (Just raw javascript). I solved the issue placing the script tag right after closing the html tag. I think it's because the DOM was not completely loaded before executing the script.

Here's an example

```
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

That way, the browser will execute the script once the whole page elements have been loaded.

The browser may give a different result when the script is in an external file. Once the code stopped working for me when i moved it to an external file while the same code worked when i wrote it inside the html script tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).